# Daily Batch file processing exception

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm accessing a SFTP server to get a .xml file that contains some information. I'm reading the file and processing the data by updating into my database whatever needs to be updated.

The file is day specific, like: "file20161117". My problem here is, how to do take care of exceptions on the following day?

Let's say my batch fails, throws an Exception and does not update. I want to create a way to verify that there are no errors left behind. Should I use a table and link it to the file's name?

Thank you for your time.
Rhaeg

Comment: It sounds like all you want to do is log errors?  Log them to a file or to a separate error database.

Comment: Have a look at SLF4J as logging facade and Logback or log4j2 as logging frameworks. You can setup logging to file, database, ... I bet someone even has an Appender for carrier pidgeons ...

Comment: Hmm I see. then I just query the files that are have the error ID and process those. Seems legit, easier than I was making it. Kinda new to this stuff. thank you